# sending UIScrollView to Background

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm midway of finishing my app. I noticed that one of my views needs extra vertical space so I need to add a UIScrollView. Yet when I add that scroll view it overlaps everything else in the view. In simple words if I need to get it to work properly I have to delete everything off the view , add the scroll view, and then re-add everything back! Is there anyway to send this scroll view to the background of the view? This is all the code that concerns the scroll view

```
@IBOutlet var scrollerForPOfFourBar: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    /* non related code here*/

    scrollerForPOfFourBar.userInteractionEnabled = true
    scrollerForPOfFourBar.self.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, 400)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using Interface Builder since you marked your scrollView as an IBOutlet.

On the view list, on the left, the order of the views specifies their Z order, with the views at the bottom being the ones drawn on top (with the largest Z).

To move your scrollView to the back, drag it just underneath of the view, and drop it there.

[image]

Keep in mind that you will have to drag all the views you had in your view into the scrollView (the easiest is to do it in the views navigator as well), and you'll have to set up any Auto Layout constraints again, which **will** be a pain.

Comment: i did what u told me and now as if the buttons and labels are hidden below the scroll view. see these screenshots                                                                         [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7awbkrn0zzcrrmq/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-11%20at%207.01.48%20PM.png?dl=0)                                                       [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r5etlgxi5vdg698/Screen%20Shot%202015-03-11%20at%207.02.12%20PM.png?dl=0)

Comment: haha. nevermind.. i had to drag them all from that textfield :P

Comment: @WassimSeifeddine if the answer helped you solve your question, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just want to move `scrollerForPOfFourBar` to back? Try this:

```
self.view.sendSubviewToBack(scrollerForPOfFourBar)
```

Comment: this  did send the scroll view to the back but it can't scroll anything now. the labels,buttons.. above it don't move even when i try to scroll even though i can see the vertical scroll indicators. i added a button to the scroll view and also the button moved to the back to labels... but i can scroll now. so i guess i have to link the label and buttons to the scroll view ?

Comment: yes. what you attach to scroll view will also move to back. so you need to attach buttons and labels to scrollView rather self.view, or anything else.

Comment: okay then how can i attach all the buttons and labels that i had before to the scroll view without deleting them and re-adding them ?