# Add a scroll view to a set view hierarchy

Tags: swift, scrollview

I have a view controller with a number of sub views, all connections made etc. I've found I now need a scroll view to allow for all the content on smaller screen sizes.

My question is how do I add a scroll view to the top of the view hierarchy and allow for scrolling of all views?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I answered this question a few days ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992374/sending-uiscrollview-to-backgroud/28992711#28992711

Comment: Thanks, so you would have to reset constraints relative to tej parent scrollview? What about setting the scrollview size?

Comment: Here is a pretty good tutorial to have the scrollView set it's contentSize property automatically based on the content. In the tutorial it uses a contentView inside the scrollView, but you don't really need it.
http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/03/05/uiscrollview-autolayout-ios/

Comment: Thanks. So if I don't use a content view and just add the views to the scroll  view, do I still need to tell the scrollview it's size or will it calculate based on views added to it?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to first create the `UIScrollView` that will contain all your subviews. Then you can iterate through all your top-level subviews and move them from their superview and into the scroll view instead.

Assuming inside your `UIViewController`:

```
// You will need to handle auto-resize, frame adjustment, and auto-layout stuff
let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.frame)

for view in self.view.subviews
{
    // Move all subviews from the main view to the scroll view
    for subView in self.view.subviews as [UIView]
    {
        subView.removeFromSuperview()
        scrollView.addSubview(subView)
    }
}

// Insert the scroll view as the first subview
self.view.insertSubview(scrollView, atIndex: 0)
```

As mentioned, you will have to handle the layout of these views (auto-resize masks, constraints, etc).